# Transaction scope with multiple connections

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

I have a process that requires a rollback of all updates and inserts should there be an error during any phase.  So i wanted to use the TransactionScope class to accomplish this.  Here is my code:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    IWE dbContext1 = null;

    using (dbContext1 = new IWE())
    {
        dbContext1.Connection.Open();

        //make some changes using the dbContext1

        //Save Changes but don't discard yet
        dbContext1.SaveChanges(false);

       //make a call to another database
       using (EPE context = new EPE())
       {

          //add or makes some changes
          context.SaveChanges(false);
       }
    }


    //if there were no problems above committ the transaction
    if (success)
    {
         ////if we get here things are looking good.
         scope.Complete();

         //accept the changes above against these connections.
         dbContext1.AcceptAllChanges();
    }
}
```

Problem is as soon as i make the call to the second connection i get the error:

> "Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been
>   disabled.  Please enable DTC for network access in the security
>   configuration for MSDTC using the  Component Services Administrative
>   tool."

I have checked to make sure that the MSDTC is enabled on both servers.  Or at least it appears so.

Other information:
- There is no firewall between them.
- First DB server is running Windows Server 2003 R2 w/ sql 2005
- Second DB server is running Windows Server 2003 w/ sql 2000

Can anyone point me in the right direction using the transaction scope w/ or w/o the use of distributed transactions?

Thanks in advance,
Billy

Comment: Enabled MSDTC service is not enough. Make sure that it is also configured to accept network access (it can be configured either through component services snap-in for MMC) or in Turn on/off windows feature.

Comment: Ladislav - We are configured to allow network access.  I went through this arcticle http://www.sqlwebpedia.com/content/msdtc-troubleshooting and everything appears to be set properly.  We have no issue querying cross server through query analyzer.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Querying doesn't matter because query doesn't use MSDTC. Try to use DTCPing to diagnose errors (you will probably have to download it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going about this a different way after alot of time spent trying to get the Distributed transactions to work.

My solution was to just use a single connection.  So I created a view on the first DB that mapped to the database table on the second DB(different server as well) that i needed to insert into.  I imported that view into my entity model as well as all three stored procedure cud statements(only using insert but need all of them) and mapped them to the entity object accordingly.

After that everything work as it should under one single connection.